# Assests folder use under Firebase Cloud Function project

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to have an `assets` folder (and maybe it also has in terms some subfolders) under `functions` folder which contains several image files. Depending on database action I'd like to copy some or all contents of that `assets` folder (or one of its subfolder) to Firebase Storage location designated with that particular `db` action. (or under `temp` folder for editing prior to sending them to Cloud Storage location)

Is this possible? I can't find any relevant information.

I know I can put those assets under Firebase Storage in the first place, I just want to keep them under `functions` in terms of keeping my project structure clean. Also, any operation in Cloud Function area of Storage is per file, no bulk folder ops.

**UPDATE:**

Indeed it is possible, one needs to use correct file/folder location in Cloud Functions while using a custom sub-folder. I'll write an answer later when I'll have free time.

Comment: its been 4 years... do you have some free time? because there is no documentation on this that I have found.

Comment: @DIGIByte it's been a long time and  I don't have a test project I can fiddle with quickly at the moment. As far as I remember answer below by LundinCast is a good one. Make sure you don't upload large files and double-check how you try to reach your asset (relative vs absolute paths, Linux vs Windows path structure etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can indeed deploy an assets folder along with your function code. For example, consider the following directory structure:

```
functions
│   index.js
│   package.json    
│
└───assets
    │   file_1.png
    │   file_2.png
    │
    └───subfolder1
        │   file_3.png
        │   file_4.png
        │   ...
```

Running the `firebase deploy ...` command within the functions folder will deploy the whole tree. Then, from your exported function in index.json, you'll be able to access your assets folder content like you'd usually do in Nodejs.

One thing to take into account with this approach though is that there are [resource limits](https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#resource_limits) applied to Cloud Functions, specifically on deployment size:

[image]

Depending on the size of your picture this may be a problem. And note that, even if the total size is within the limits, the bigger it is the longer it will take to deploy when scaling up.

Comment: I tried to upload an image via the assets folder but I am not able to read that image in firebase functions. Can you throw some light on that? Basically I am using that static image to merge with the user profile picture using image magick.

Comment: You probably forgot to copy the assets files to the 'dist' folder as they are not copied when you do npm run build.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above solution but falied

you can convert your files in base64 and top of your function you can convert the bas64 file to your files and save it in `os.tmpdir()` and use it anywhere in your function.

Here is the example of how I put my font in cloud functions for later use

```
function writeFontsInTempDir() {
  const banglaFont = 'Your base64'
  fs.writeFileSync(path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'bangla_font.ttf'), banglaFont, {encoding: 'base64'});

  const englishFont= 'Your base64'
  fs.writeFileSync(path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'english_font.ttf'), englishFont, {encoding: 'base64'});
}
```

for later use, you can just call

```
const bangla_font_path = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'bangla_font.ttf');
const english_font_path = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'english_font.ttf');
```

You will need these imports

```
import * as os from 'os';
import * as path from 'path';
```